# how to add single scroll to view and listview in same layout in android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a situation, in that situation one view contain imageviews on upper part and list view in the lower part and when we scrolling it is only scroll listview part but i have to scroll whole view simultaneously with single scroll.
                            I have used add header functionality of  list view but in that i have to put seperate xml file of imageview and listview and i need to put them in one xml file. how can i do it..

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_relativelayout" >

    <!-- //settings  First view  Setting -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_chooseteam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="d"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_cbk"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/cbk_btn" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_chooseteam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="d"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_cfb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/cfb_btn" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_chooseteam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="d"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_mlb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/mlb_btn" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_chooseteam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="d"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="@string/Games_Placebet_chooseteam"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_chooseteam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="d"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_nba"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/nba_btn" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_chooseteam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="d"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_nfl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/nfl_btn" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_chooseteam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="d"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_nhl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/nhl_btn" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_chooseteam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="d"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="@string/Games_Placebet_chooseteam"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="12sp"

                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/middle_line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first_view"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/small_line"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/small_line" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="f"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="5sp"

                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_header_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/middle_line" >



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dd"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Recent Activities"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_header_layout" >


            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@id/android:list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/first_view"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:childDivider="@android:color/black"
                android:divider="@android:color/black"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:scrollingCache="false" >
            </ExpandableListView>

        </LinearLayout> 
    </RelativeLayout>
    //settings  Second view  Setting

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressrelative"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar2"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/channellist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_relativelayout"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:scrollingCache="false" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/betView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_chooseteam"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="@string/Games_Placebet_chooseteam"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/gm4_headar_parch"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/button_date_time"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="Saturday, 10/27/2012 at 01:00 PM"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="13sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gm4_1white_bg"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/button_hometeam"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:text="Denver Broncos"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView_button_hometeam"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/game_click_btn" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/recent_bigpatch_line" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/button_visitorteam"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="SD Chargers"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView_button_visitorteam"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/game_unclick_btn" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Betting Amount"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/upper_relative"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/gm4_headar_parch"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_placebet_balance"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/Games_Placebet_balance"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <!--
                     <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_placebet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:paddingRight="32dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:text="$"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                    -->

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_placebet_dollar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:text="100"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gm4_1white_bg"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/button_placebet_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Denver Broncos"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/recent_bigpatch_line" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_placebet_up_counter"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/pg_2_up_arrow_btn" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/textview_placebet_counter_digipanel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/counter_digitaldisplay"
                            android:textColor="#109EE6" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_placebet_counter_down"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/pg_2_down_arrow_btn" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_betaganist"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/bet_against_btn_new"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/Games_Placebet_betaganist"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_placebet"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/placebet_btn_new"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Place Bet"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/friendlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_relativelayout"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollingCache="false" >
    </ListView>
</ViewFlipper>
```

here is a code of xml file in which i have used viewflipper  and in that i have added views so the first view is image view on upper side listview on the lower side when we click on image view next view will flip and so on...  but in the first view  it is  scrolling only listview part i need to scroll whole view with single scroll.

THanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, all the possible ways to mix in two scrolls does not yield well ( to best of my knowledge), Setting the header xml is probably the best approach for it. try to find a way around the situation.